# delete all graph data in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, chart-design

I've created a graph in illustrator, and I would like to delete the current data so I can enter new data. When I select all the cells and press the delete key, it only deletes the first cell in the selection, not all of the cells. Is there a way to delete all the data at once without having to delete each individual cell?

[image: selected all the data]

[image: hit delete key, and it only deletes one cell]

Answer (score 1):

I've found the graph feature in Illustrator to be a little glitchy at times, even basic/primitive, and definitely in need of some love and attention from Adobe. I've certainly noticed slight usability differences or annoyances depending on which version of AI or which OS you are running.

In Windows 10, in Illustrator CC 2017.1.0 highlight the cells, and press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key (not <kbd>backspace</kbd>).  Of course this is weird even on Windows, and really I have to ask "WHY ADOBE?"

On an Old Windows 7 laptop I have with AI CS4, neither delete nor backspace work properly with the graph data.

Obviously a Mac keyboard only has one <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, so I assume you have tried that and it isn't working. I don't have access to one right now to check.

If the <kbd>Delete</kbd> fails, try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> on Mac - this is the "cut" shortcut.